# Windows Forms Application: Mysterious Closing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms Application that mysteriously crashes. There is no error message that comes up, and there is no user related event that causes the close. A user will turn around to do filing and the program has disappeared and work is lost. I am not running any extra threads, and am only doing processes after an event(clicking buttons).

I checked the Admin Tools->Event Viewer->Windows Logs and there was no Error Entry for the time that program closed.

How do I collect any information about this error?
Would there even be an error in an ALL ENCOMPASSING try->catch?
Is the problem external to the program itself?(The user will be running memory intensive apps)

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/catching-unhandled-exceptions/ < maybe go down this route. At least just for reassurance that there are none being raised.

Comment: Test it on a different machine and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: You probably have a `catch` clause that is discarding the error. Trying to make an “ALL ENCOMPASSING try->catch” is exactly the wrong thing to do; you need to remove your try/catch clauses so the runtime reports the error instead of discarding it.

Comment: Also, if you are using the TaskFactory object in .NET4 to run code Async and not checking/handling the AggregateException on the resultant Task object, when the GC runs on the Task object it will throw an unhandled exception if the Task has not had it's AggregateException handled.

Comment: There exists only one try->catch that will only happen when an event happens(submit button). (Thanks btw)

Comment: Check your event viewer - this sounds to me like it could be a stack overflow - or possibly stack corruption, if you use platform invoke.

Comment: It could be some kind of error, which skips some of the code. Try adding multiple `try/catch` clauses in your code, and use `catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }`, so you'll see the error message. Another idea is to debug the code line by line to find the error.